# How to disable non-english keys, but keep their AltGr meaning

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, internationalization

I have a non-english keyboard and it has all sorts of unusual keys for letters of my language. But I very rarely have to use them, they are rather just annoying when I accidentally press them. I wounder if I could disable them so pressing them would not type anything at all. However some of them have a useful AltGr meaning that I would like to keep enabled.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using? One possibility is to create a custom keyboard layout where you drop some symbols.